# Can't Diagnose jQuery Error: "Object [object Object] has no method"

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, mediaelement

I'm working on a Wordpress theme and right now I'm trying to get MediaElement to display audio files on posts.

jQuery is loading fine (tested with jQuery alerts) but for some reason MediaElement doesn't want to work. I get the error

```
'Object [object Object] has no method 'mediaelementplayer','
```

and although I've double checked everything I just can't figure out what's wrong. If you need a live demo of the problem, check it out here: http://firstpersontheater.net/video/podcast/painkiller-already-episode-78 (please don't judge the theme, I'm working on getting core functionality done first and haven't really started designing yet, haha).

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me with the WordPress plugin:

```
mejs.$('.mejs-player').mediaelementplayer();
```

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem yesterday as well.

MediaElement.js actually includes several different files in the download package. In order to get the full-featured video player you have to include the "mediaelement-and-player.js" file, not the "mediaelement.js" file, which is just the library.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same issue.

While I was unable to isolate exactly why this error occurs with the WordPress plug-in implementation of MediaElement.js, I was able to move past it by using the JavaScript of MediaElement only.

I modified the PHP to output the relevant audio and video HTML tags without ID's, and without the script that calls them. I also removed the aspects of the plug-in for cueing scripts, instead linking them myself in my theme.

I then had success calling MediaElement normally using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Well what library are you using that adds the api `mediaelementplayer`? Looks like that plugin either isnt loaded correctly or you are using the API incorrectly.

Comment: I'm using [MediaElementJS](http://mediaelementjs.com/) and the thing that's stumping me is that I continue to get the error even though the script shows as loaded in Chrome's 'Resources' tab. I also believe I'm calling it correctly because on their website they use [the same '.mediaelement' call (pic)](http://i.imgur.com/sGmvV.png)

Comment: I think in their case the $ is referring to something else not query.. if you see closely at the example they are using jQuery(document).ready() and not $(document).ready(). I would confirm the $ here first

Comment: I am not sure though.. can you check on what object you need to use the method `mediaelementplayer`?

Comment: I know I need to use it on the 'audio' object, but since I have two on the same page (different sizes necessary) I have called them separately by their specific IDs.

Comment: also looks like you are importing the jquery library twice.. not sure if there is some conflict cos of the same

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

You trying to to call a method that does not exits.

```
var o = {a = 1, b = 2};
o.someFunctionIThinkShoudExist();
```

It would be nice if it showed what the name of the function you were trying to call was. This happened to me last week and I resolved it by making sure I had linked to the correct JavaScript files.

What you can check is that you are only linking to the libraries you are using, like jQuery, only once. If you link to jQuery and a jQuery extention, then linking to jQuery again will unbind the extension. Causing the above error when you try to call the function you think should exits.